# Gitlab integrated with bamboo - neverending pending state on gitlab while success on bamboo

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, bamboo

I integrated gitlab 8.1.4 with bamboo 5.9.7 build 5920
according to http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/project_services/bamboo.html

Now after push, bamboo successfully builds code for that branch (green status on bamboo), but there is no return info to Gitlab.
Gitlab shows pending state on merge request page.

Comment: Do you have application links enabled?

Comment: @dhumketu No, i do not. How to enable it ? is there any tutorial ? I found only [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/APPLINKS/OAuth+security+for+application+links) But i configure OAuth first time so i have no idea what URIs i should enter

Comment: How are you merging?

Comment: @dhumketu merging ? I create new feature branch in eclipse, make some commits, push to gitlab, build on bamboo is spawned (bamboo correctly detects all new branches). I create merge request, it says build is pending. Build on bamboo ends. Gitlab still says: CI build pending for <commit hash>. I click Accept Merge Request. It says: "Something went wrong during merge"